Wierd chart layout with pandas/matplotlib line chart
I am new to Data Science and Python/NumPy/Pandas world in general.  I have a dataset which is an order/order line item/product dataset.  I am trying to plot a basic line chart with pandas:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

data_link = "https://<github_link>/orders.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(data_link, encoding='latin-1')
daily_sales = (data
             .groupby('Order Date')    # dimensions
             .agg({'Sales': 'sum'})    # metric
        )

daily_sales.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(daily_sales.index)
fig, my_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 4))
daily_sales.plot(ax=my_ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


It should ideally look like this:

I did try .sort_values(by='Sales') to the groupby as some suggested that it is because that the X axis values are not sorted.  Though X axis is Order Date, I tried .sort_values(by='Order Date') to begin with.  Still similar graph.  Totally confused.  Please help.

If I remove daily_sales.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(daily_sales.index), and rerun everything, I get the needed output.  But as per what I were asked to do, I am supposed to use this above line to convert the object/string Order Date to DateTime64 first, so we can also see weekly and monthly trends using resample() method.

When you did .sort_values, did you reassign it? df.sort_values(by='Sales') alone will not save the results; you need to reassign the variable with df = df.sort_values(by='Sales').

Or add in_place=True.

@Mahesh It's a little hard to read code that's posted in comments - SE comments don't have great support for code formatting. Can you [edit] your question to include it instead?

Thanks @anerdw.  I have reassigned them.  I assume the code:
 daily_sales = (data 
 groupby(by='Order Date')       # dimensions
.    agg({'Sales': 'sum'})          # metric
.    sort_values(by='Sales') 
  )
   ```       

I assume this does the reassignment.  Sales or Order Date which I need to sort I am unclear about.  The suggestion I saw was that the X axis (Order Date) has to be sorted.  That also gives the same wierd graph!

@Mahesh Seems like you might be having a hard time finding the edit feature. Click this link to edit your question: [edit].

you need to order your daily_sales by the index, not the Sales columns. so daily_sales = daily_sales.sort_index() before plot. For example:
daily_sales.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(daily_sales.index)
daily_sales = daily_sales.sort_index()

fig, my_ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 4))
daily_sales.plot(ax=my_ax)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

